# How to set name for java -jar process and store pid to file

Tags: command-line, bash, java, jar

I would like to set name for process which triggers java -jar command. For example this command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub
```

I would like to set this process name and store its pid to file. Like other services e.g. Apache has its name next to pid. But all java commands are named as java and it is useless. I found some scripts to store pid but it looks like it is super complicated. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Set a different name for your process: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11130229/start-a-process-with-a-name

Comment: I have this but it does not work. Still named as java `bash -c "exec -a SeleniumHub java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub &"`